# VTK file format to image file

Tags: visualization, vtk

Is there a way to convert vtk file without visualizing into a image file such as png in the bash terminal itself?

I have found that for the vtk files that I visualize to take longer time than its corresponding image file (which is made from a different file).

Comment: do you mean save a "screenshot" as png file? Or your vtk data is already a 2D image?

Comment: I was trying to visualize vtk file in paraview, but it was too slow, so I converted it into png and then visualized it. So basically, when I was visualizing vtk actively it was too slow, so i wanted a method to input functions in a script and get the result as post processing, as converting all the files to png was a pain, but eventually I made a script to do that

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about "in the bash terminal itself", but I use python scripting with Visit.  See [here](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=VisIt-tutorial-Python-scripting) or [here](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Python_examples) for some examples.

Below I have pasted a simple script I use to make an image of a 2D slice along y = 0.5 of a 3D cube. The script is named "script.py" and "ysolution" refers to a variable name with the .vtk file.

```
# invoke like so: visit -cli -nowin -s script.py ysolution-19.vtk ysolution

import os,sys
wholefile = os.getcwd() + "/" + sys.argv[-2]
fieldname = sys.argv[-1]

OpenDatabase(wholefile)
AddPlot("Pseudocolor",fieldname)
AddOperator("Slice")
s = SliceAttributes()
s.originIntercept = 0.5
SetOperatorOptions(s)
DrawPlots()
t = SaveWindowAttributes()
t.fileName = "y19-"
SetSaveWindowAttributes(t)
n = SaveWindow()
print n

quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [**mayavi**](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) (distributed in [pythonxy](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) for instance) for this task. Assuming the vtk file is `my_input_file.vtk` and you wish to display a vector field in a cut plane using glyphs then save as png image, the following methods do the trick:

- Save your vtk as an image directly from the terminal:

  `$ mayavi2 -d my_input_file.vtk -m VectorCutPlane -f MaskPoints -m Glyph \
             -s "scene.save('my_image.png')"`
- Or, alternatively wrap things up in an executable shell script `mayavi_script.sh` containing:

  `mayavi2 -d my_input_file.vtk \
           -m VectorCutPlane \
           -f MaskPoints \
           -m Glyph \
           -s "scene.save('my_image.png')"`

  In the both cases, the switches `-d` , `-m`, `-f` and `-s` stand respectively for datafile, [module](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/modules.html#modules), [filter](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/filters.html#filters) and executable python expression. This is only an example, but many other things can be done after checking the documentation. The `-o` is **very useful to parse the commands in off-screen mode**, therefore no GUI will be opened.
- For more advanced offscreen visualization with image output, you can write and python-run a mayavi script (in the same idea suggested by Andrew T. Barker's answer for Visit) using the [mlab](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) and its pipeline module:

  `import mayavi.mlab as ml
   ml.options.offscreen = True
   ...`